# Is there a third-party Finder app that remembers custom column widths in List View?

Tags: macos, finder, customization

My understanding is that it is **impossible** to change the default width of the List View "Name" column in Finder on a Mac. To be specific, I need to *increase* this width.

Is there a third-party program that can accomplish this?

If so, please specify if the "Name" column width can be set on a

- per-folder basis
- system-wide (all folders basis)
- or both.

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

On the latest version of Sierra, in list view in a Finder window, holding the option key while double-clicking the divider between the “Name” column and its adjacent column. then releasing the option key and closing then reopening Finder to that same folder… the width of your name column retains its new set value in list view.  This only works on a per folder basis You can set custom widths for your name columns in list view for any folder of your choosing.

Here's the kicker though!!  I believe if you resize the finder window itself, this will reset your custom column widths.

[image]

Comment: I think you can also Alt + Drag, Instead of Alt + double-clicking

Comment: I'm still on El Capitan for now, but I will try your solution after upgrading to Sierra.

Comment: I think my solution works on El Capitan as well

Comment: This does not work on El Capitan. If I hold the _option_ key while double-clicking the divider while in List View, the full width of the "Name" column is temporarily maintained (that is, only while this window is open). If I close this window, and then re-open the very same folder, the "Name" column is in the truncated state again. I did not re-size the Finder window, at any point.